# passing object to javascript in rubyonrails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

My `MapsController` is

```
def show
   @outlet=OUtlet.all
   render 'maps/map'
end
```

My View page is `map.html.erb`

```
<% @outlet.each do |product| %>
    <%= product.latitude %>
    <%= product.longitude %>
<% end %>
```

The result is

```
   51.503454  -0.119562  51.499633 -0.124755 51.489633  -0.123755 51.479633  -0.122755
```

I need to pass the array to .js as below `format`.

```
var markers = [
    [ 51.503454,-0.119562],
    [ 51.499633,-0.124755],
    [ 51.489633,-0.123755],
    [ 51.479633,-0.122755]
];
```

I tried with some example like `javascript_tag`, `attribute method` with no luck. Can anyone help to sort it out.

The above format is to plot the marker in google-map.

Comment: Can you please tell me where you are going to place your javascript, in map.html.erb or somewhere else?

Comment: yes,. in map.html.erb only

Answer (score 0):

You can write a helper method to return a array of latitude and longitude values.

```
module MapsHelper
  def outlet_lat_lons(outlets)
    lat_lons = []
    outlets.each do |outlet|
      lat_lons << [outlet.latitude, outlet.longitude]
    end
  end 
end
```

Then in your js code call this helper

```
var markers = <%= outlet_lat_lons(@outlets) %>;
```

Comment: Let me know if above answer helps.